# mysql query not formatting correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am very close on this but still having a problem with the listing of events. What I am looking for is for the title, date and event to show once with a list of names who participated in that event. Now I am getting an event, date and title printed as many times as names, with only one name showing in each.

I have tried GROUP BY on several fields but nothing seems to work.

```
SELECT x.xdate, x.xevent, x.xname, x.xaffirm, y.activity, y.title,
y.text, y.date 
    FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON x.xdate = y.date 
    WHERE xevent='Hiking' AND xaffirm='Yes'
    ORDER BY y.date DESC") 

Print "<table width=500>"; 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 

Print "<tr>"; 
Print 
"<th style='width:225px;' bgcolor=#49A78D align=center >Title</th>
<th style='width:300px;' bgcolor=#49A78D align=center >Text</th>
<th style='width:175px;' bgcolor=#49A78D align=center >Date</th> 
<th style='width:175px;' bgcolor=#49A78D align=center >Name</th>"; 
Print "</tr>";

Print "<tr>"; 
 Print 
"<td bgcolor=#ffffff valign=top  align=center>".$info['title'] . "</td>
 <td bgcolor=#ffffff valign=top align=left>".$info['text'] . "</td>
 <td bgcolor=#ffffff valign=top align=left>".$info['date'] . "</td>
 <td bgcolor=#ffffff valign=top align=left>".$info['name'] . "</td>";
 Print "</tr>";
```

This is what I am getting now:[undesired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w31k7.jpg)

This is what I would like to get: [desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESiAw.jpg)

Comment: Please show the lines you get and those you want instead.

Comment: This is what I am getting now

Comment: @rsw - he's asking what your output looks like now, and what you'd like it to look like.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks had trouble getting the photos to upload.

Comment: Many people have an aversion to running multiple queries. A very straightforward (and simpler) way to do what you're asking is run an additional query (participants) for each row of the response (hikes). It's a bit slower to process, but in most cases the performance difference is unlikely to be noticed by users. It has the upside of making the code easier to read.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding this. The selected columns in the query don't match the columns read in the PHP script. What does table x contain? Events? No, then it would not contain a single person's name. A person's confirmation to take part in an event? But then, what does table y contain? Why is it only linked by date? And xevent='Hiking' doesn't sound like one event, but rather like an event type. So please show table data. And please don't show images, but formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd probably do is to have a single variable that denotes "does the data in this row correspond to a new event, or is it additional data for the same event?"

If the date doesn't match, it's a new event; first, add a new header row, then add a new row with data for all four columns. If the date does match, then skip the header and add a row where the first three columns are empty and the fourth has the new name. (Apologies if my PHP doesn't quite compile, it's been a while.)

```
$lastEventDate = '';
Print "<table width=500>"; 

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
    if ($lastEventDate != $info['date'])
    {
        Print "<tr>"; 
        Print 
        "<th style='width:225px;' bgcolor=#49A78D align=center >Title</th>
        <th style='width:300px;' bgcolor=#49A78D align=center >Text</th>
        <th style='width:175px;' bgcolor=#49A78D align=center >Date</th> 
        <th style='width:175px;' bgcolor=#49A78D align=center >Name</th>"; 
        Print "</tr>";
    }

    Print "<tr>"; 
    if ($lastEventDate == $info['date'])
    {
        Print "<td colspan=3 />"
    }
    else
    {
        Print 
        "<td bgcolor=#ffffff valign=top  align=center>".$info['title'] . "</td>
        <td bgcolor=#ffffff valign=top align=left>".$info['text'] . "</td>
        <td bgcolor=#ffffff valign=top align=left>".$info['date'] . "</td>"
    }
    Print "<td bgcolor=#ffffff valign=top align=left>".$info['name'] . "</td>";
    Print "</tr>";
    $lastEventDate = $info['date'];
}
```

Also, I'm unsure whether what you actually want is separate tables; if so, then inside the first `if` block, you can close the first table, then open a new one.

Comment: Hi Adam, I substituted your changes but the problem persists. Also I should mention there are multiple individual events I would like to list each with the appropriate dates and who participants.

Comment: @rsw - Ah, I think I understand. So you'd like a new header row every time the `$info['xdate']` refers to a new event?

Comment: Although thinking about this more, it might be nicer to do `rowspans` on the `td`s, instead of new rows with `colspans`.

Comment: Yes. new header for every new event.

Comment: . . . .now getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 56

Comment: @rsw - what's on line 56?